# Parameter passing to a function which return Index By Table value

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I have following an example in a pl/sql document (PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference)

```
1   DECLARE
2   TYPE sum_multiples IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
3   n PLS_INTEGER := 5; -- number of multiples to sum for display
4   sn PLS_INTEGER := 10; -- number of multiples to sum
5   m PLS_INTEGER := 3; -- multiple
6   FUNCTION get_sum_multiples(multiple IN PLS_INTEGER, num IN PLS_INTEGER)
7   RETURN sum_multiples IS
8   s sum_multiples;
9   BEGIN
10  FOR i IN 1..num LOOP
11  s(i) := multiple * ((i * (i + 1)) / 2) ; -- sum of multiples
12  END LOOP;
13  RETURN s;
14  END get_sum_multiples;
15  BEGIN
16  #NAME?
17  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sum of the first ' || TO_CHAR(n) || ' multiples of ' ||
18  TO_CHAR(m) || ' is ' || TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n)));
19  END;
20  /
```

Sum of the first 5 multiples of 3 is 45

I am unable to understand "TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n))" in line no 18.
How the parameters are passed, there is no separator between (m, sn)(n) despite this code works.
Can anyone answer about this code.

I changed the function call from
TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n))
to
TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn),(n))
But it returned error

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to understand "TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n))" in line no 18

- function name is `get_sum_multiples`
- it accepts two parameters:

  - `multiple` - it gets its value from `m`
  - `num` - it gets its value from `sn`
- `(n)` which confuses you isn't parameter but n-th member of index by table; that's why it doesn't make sense to separate `(m, sn)` and `(n)` with a comma

If you add some more *debugging* info into that procedure, you'll see this:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE sum_multiples IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  3     n   PLS_INTEGER := 5; -- number of multiples to sum for display
  4     sn  PLS_INTEGER := 10; -- number of multiples to sum
  5     m   PLS_INTEGER := 3; -- multiple
  6
  7     FUNCTION get_sum_multiples(multiple IN PLS_INTEGER, num IN PLS_INTEGER)
  8       RETURN sum_multiples
  9     IS
 10       s sum_multiples;
 11     BEGIN
 12       FOR i IN 1..num LOOP
 13         s(i) := multiple * ((i * (i + 1)) / 2) ; -- sum of multiples
 14         dbms_output.put_line('s(' || i||') = ' || s(i));
 15       END LOOP;
 16       RETURN s;
 17     END get_sum_multiples;
 18
 19     BEGIN
 20       --#NAME?
 21       dbms_output.put_line('m = ' || m ||', sn = ' || sn ||', n = ' || n);
 22
 23       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sum of the first ' || TO_CHAR(n) || ' multiples of ' ||
 24         TO_CHAR(m) || ' is ' || TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n)));
 25     END;
 26    /
```

Output is:

```
m = 3, sn = 10, n = 5
s(1) = 3
s(2) = 9
s(3) = 18
s(4) = 30
s(5) = 45              --> this is what function returned
s(6) = 63
s(7) = 84
s(8) = 108
s(9) = 135
s(10) = 165
Sum of the first 5 multiples of 3 is 45

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already did the debugging asked by you and got the same output . Difference was that I put DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(s(i)); instead of  dbms_output.put_line('s(' || i||') = ' || s(i));  I was confused about n in TO_CHAR(get_sum_multiples (m, sn)(n)). By your answer it is clear that we can refer index element using such notation in function call which returns a collection type value, am I correct?

Comment: You're welcome. It is not that we "can refer index element using such notation", but we *have to refer it* that way; that's the syntax, you don't have other options.